# Android web app keyboard doesn't resize view when web app open once

Tags: android, web-applications, keyboard

I experience a weird behavior on web app added to home screen on Android devices when keyboard appears.

I have a web app:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
</head>
<body style="overflow-y: scroll">
    <div id="red" style="height:200px;width:100%;background-color:red"></div>
    <input type="text">
    <script>
        (function() {
            var baseH = window.innerHeight;
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                if (window.innerHeight<baseH) {
                    document.getElementById('red').innerHTML = 'KEYBOARD';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('red').innerHTML = 'NO KEYBOARD';
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I open the web app, click on the input field, keyboard appears but resize event is not triggered.

If I press recent application on my android device and I click on the current web app to go back in it and then click in input field keyboard appears and resize event is triggered.

How can I make resize event triggered when I open the web app at the first time?

Tested on Nexus4, Nexus5 and Nexus7 all on Android 4.4.x

Answer (score 0):

That's because `height=device-height` has been set in the viewport meta tag. Removing it should fix the problem.

Comment: No it doesn't fix the case. I haven't find a solution yet.

Comment: any news? :( im looking for a solution too